# CRM opportunity entity will not open "New Opportunity Product"

Tags: dynamics-crm, product

I am currently experiencing an issue within my Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 Opportunity entity. When I try to input a new opportunity product. I select the button on the form “New Opportunity Product,” but instead of opening this, it does nothing at all. What could cause this to happen? And how would I go about fixing this issue for it is a critical part of our business. If you need a screen shot please let me know. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it. 
Software/Hardware used:
Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any products in the crm product catalog? Perhaps you need to add some.

Comment: I have added a few because at first that is what i thought the problem was, but its still not working for some reason.